# How to print two elements from an iterate list in python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

```
x = ["a","b","c","d","e"]

for a in range(len(x)-1):
    print(x[a],x[a+1])
```

output is :

```
a b
b c
c d
d e
```

but I want results like this :

```
a b
c d
e
```

please help me what should i do with the looping

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
x = ["a","b","c","d","e"]

for a in range(0,len(x),2):
    try:
        print(x[a],x[a+1])
    except:
        print(x[a])
```

Output of this code :

```
a b
c d
e
```

Answer (score 0):

So you can do this:

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

for a in range(1, len(x) + 1):
    print(x[a-1], x[a])
```

or with list comprehension:
print(x[a-i], x[a]) for a in range(1, len(x)+1)

Answer (score 0):

Try to split the list into smaller lists, with only two elements each.

For example:

```
x = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]

splitted_list = [x[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(x), 2)]

for element in splitted_list:
    print(', '.join(element))
```

or, if you don't feel comfortable enough with list comprehension:

```
x = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
splitted_list = []

for i in range(0, len(x), 2):
    splitted_list.append(x[i:i+2])

for element in splitted_list:
    print(', '.join(element))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using while loop

```
x = ["a","b","c","d","e"]

i=0

while i< len(x):
    try:
        print(x[i],x[i+1])
    except:
        print(x[i])
    i=i+2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = ["a","b","c","d","e"]

res = []
tmp =[]
for i in x:
    if len(tmp)==2:
        res.append(tmp)
        tmp =[i]
    else:
        tmp.append(i)
        
if tmp:
    res.append(tmp)
    
for i in res:
    print(*i)
```

Answer (score 0):

using `itertools` [zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)

```
from itertools import zip_longest

x = ["a","b","c","d","e"]

for a, b in zip_longest(x[::2], x[1::2]):
    print(a, b)
```

---

```
a b
c d
e None
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = ["a","b","c","d","e"]
i=0
while i<len(x):
    print(x[i],end=" ")
    if i+1<len(x):
        print(x[i+1])
        i+=1
    i+=1
```

Try it.